# LG G4 not recognised by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I just got the LG G4 phone, turned on developer options mode, tried running an app from Android Studio but it can't recognise my phone. I even tried switching from MTP to PTP but still it's not recognised. I tried a lot of resources out there, still nothing. Please can anyone help?

Comment: are you installed driver?

Comment: yes i did, still nothing

Answer (score 89, accepted):

So i restarted my device, and switched USB options from MTP to PTP. and for some reason it worked. I dont know why. Thanks for answers above, much appreciated

Comment: user3137376: I just got a G4 and had the very same problem.  Your post saved the day for me.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: Seems LG blocked debug mode work in MTP mode. It immediately starts working when switching to PTP mode

Comment: Strange that LG blocks the ADB when in any other mode than PTP, this could definitely be a bug on these devices! It only works in PTP.

Comment: @Alfishe I don't know if this was true at the time but my phone is up to date and as of today, the debug features works on MTP PTP and even MIDI mode.

Comment: This is strange because on my Lenovo Z4070 worked fine without any change, but I had to do this step on my HP Probook. You really save my day.

Comment: Worked for me too with the LG Q Stylus (LM-Q71OEM). Switching the USB options to PTP and it immediately started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem and tried everything mentioned above with no success. What ended up working for me was downloading the LG Android USB device Drivers which can be found here: http://www.mylgphones.com/lg-android-usb-device-drivers

The latest drivers didn't work for me so I downloaded the second latest and voila! It worked! Hope this helps.

Comment: I also had to install the drivers. Here's the official link (latest worked for me): http://www.lg.com/us/lgeai/drivers. Direct link (as of the time of this comment): http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425

Comment: Thank you @Henry Thomas after install drive from LG work fine. In my case when I connect USB the Smartphone ask if I want install drive and I click in yes! rs

Comment: For me I had to go on the USB options when plugging the phone to get a prompt to install drivers on PC, THEN click the .exe suggested by Windows autoplay window to continue installation.

Comment: This is the better answer. The LG drivers give you access to MTP

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers here worked for me until I turned on USB debugging mode in Developer Options.

For completeness, the steps are:

1. Go to Settings > About phone > Software info
2. Tap "Build number" 7 times until it says that you're a developer
3. Go back to Settings, and tap on the new "Developer options" item (second last in the menu)
4. Enable "USB debugging"
5. Plug in your phone
6. Change from MTP to PTP mode
7. Allow the computer to access your phone (there should be two messages - one of them should be for the RSA key fingerprint)

And that should do it. Run `adb devices` and you should see the phone.

Comment: This one is the better answer! Enabling "USB debugging" was crucial for me. If you wonder why it's greyed out. You can only change this setting when NOT connected to the computer.

Comment: For me the missed step was "Change from MTP to PTP mode".

Answer (score 6):

switched USB options from MTP to PTP. when you try to switch it will ask to install drivers then clicked on Install ....now you can debug your app on device

Answer (score 3):

Check your phone, it will ask to install driver on PC. Afterwards android studio will see your phone

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I had to do:

1. Install the *LG Mobile Drivers*: http://lg.com/us/lgeai/drivers (latest at the time of writing: [here](http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425))
2. Disable USB debugging if currently enabled (this was key for me)
3. Enable USB debugging
4. Plug into computer
5. Allow USB debugging when prompted (will show RSA fingerprint, check "always allow").
6. Trust the computer when prompted (allow access)
7. Switch to PTP
8. Install USB driver when prompted
9. Wait for the driver to finish installing on your PC

`adb devices` should show your phone now. If you don't get some of the prompts above, try unplugging and re-plugging your device. Also try different USB ports on your machine.

Comment: Installing drivers solved the issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: Mine was from [this](https://www.lg.com/ae/support/support-mobile/lg-H818P) link.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I was checking **Developer Options** after plugging USB cable, the **USB Debugging** option was unchecked and grayed out while cable plugged. I unplugged USB cable, checked USB Debugging option and plugged USB cable again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an LGL58VL test handset.  Other (non-LG) handsets worked without problem.  Installing the Google USB driver didn't help (Windows said "installed driver (LGE Android Net MTP Device) is already up to date".

Here's what worked for me

1. WINDOWS: Download and install LG driver on Windows: 
   http://lg.com/us/lgeai/drivers
2. HANDSET: Enable developer mode:

   Settings > Software Info > Tab "Build number"  7 times
3. HANDSET:

   Settings > Developer options >

   - Enable USB debugging => YES
   - Select USB Configuration => MTP
4. WINDOWS:

   Plug in handset.  "Action" => Nothing
5. HANDSET: Accept RSA key
6. WINDOWS: Android Studio > Tools > Connection Assistant >

   Verify handset device is listed and available for debugging

ALSO: sometimes, after I enabled other test devices, the "Enable USB Debugging" option for the handset became grayed out.

7. WORKAROUND (Handset):

   Settings > Developer Options >

   - Turn Developer Options OFF (slider at the top)
   - Turn Developer Options back ON
   - I was now able to hold down "USB Debugging" and slide it back to "ON"

Answer (score -1):

You have to activate developer mode for your device.

Comment: i did, i said it above

Answer (score -1):

Try tap "adb devices" in shell window( or command window)
1) if still nothing displayed, it must be not related to studio, please check whether drivers is properly installed or register in system(Different system has different methods).
2) if displayed like "0b63d5xxxxxxxxxx  device", it should be studio's problem, check view option or reinstall android studio.