# getAllCellInfo() returns an empty list in Huawei Honor 7

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I am having an android application that fetches information of cell towers. I use this getAllCellInfo() to fetch info of a primary cell and neighbour cells. I included the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission to manifest.xml and make a request for the permission in runtime.
It works in other phones but in Huawei Honor 7, the function returns an empty list. 
 
My code:
[image]
Catlog:
[image]

I have checked other people questions:
[getAllCellInfo returns null in android 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1) and [Android getAllCellInfo() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436761/android-getallcellinfo-returns-null).

From a question, I thought for Huawei phones, they don't support getAllCellInfo() until I installed [Network Cell Info Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilysis.cellinfolite&hl=en) and [NetMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.mroczis.netmonster&hl=en), and it seems that the applications can fetch the cell information in Huawei Honor 7:

Network Cell Info Lite
[image]
NetMonster 
[image]

Anybody has any information about this?

Comment: Hey phuwin, did you manage to find a solution for this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Royz not really though...

Comment: Hi, phuwin! Did you find the solution? Why NetworkCellInfo working well?

Answer (score 2):

For a little work around when there is no cell in `getAllCellInfo()`, I use `getCellLocation()` to get the primaryCellId and trackingAreaCode like this:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "updateCurrentCell: can't find any cells with getAllCellInfo");
    CellLocation primaryLocation = telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
    if (primaryLocation != null) {
        int primaryCellId = Integer.parseInt(primaryLocation.toString().split(",")[1]);
        int trackingAreaCode = Integer.parseInt(primaryLocation.toString().split(",")[0].replace("[", ""));
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateCurrentCell: not even with getCellLocation");
    }
```

Comment: When i'm printing the primaryLocation object i'm getting the following line: 'primaryLocation: GsmCellLocation:[...]'

Answer (score 2):

Although this comes late, it might be helpful for others that come across the same problem.

**First let me explain the problem:**

- I was trying to use `getAllCellInfo()` in my app.
- The app went smooth on Android Emulator (single Sim Emulator).
- Then I tried it on "*Dual Sim, Huawei CAM-L21*" running Android 6.0 and "*Dual Sim, Honor 3c*" running Android 4.4.2, as well. But on Huawei, `getAllCellInfo()` returned ***Empy List***, and ***null*** on Honor.
- I tried using "LG K8". But Android Studio could not recognize the phone. I could not find the phone driver (for windows) on LG website! So I installed some general ADB drivers. Unfortunately, Android Studio did not recognize the phone again.
- The app **worked** well on some **single sim** Huawei and Samsung phones; I cannot recall the models!

**then:**

- I found [this page](https://github.com/henrichg/PhoneProfilesPlus/blob/master/phoneProfilesPlus/src/main/java/sk/henrichg/phoneprofilesplus/PhoneStateScanner.java) where mentioned that `getAllCellInfo` might not work on some phones:

  `private void getAllCellInfo(List<CellInfo> cellInfo) {
      // only for registered cells is returned identify
      // SlimKat in Galaxy Nexus - returns null :-/
      // Honor 7 - returns empty list (not null), Dual SIM?
      // ...
  }`
- I found [this page (LG G4 not recognised by Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445662/lg-g4-not-recognised-by-android-studio). According to [Henry Thomas's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34885951/3029388), I downloded the LG driver; and finally, Android Studio reconized the LG K8 phone.
- And, finally my app worked on a dual sim phone.

**So, my findings:**

- `getAllCellInfo` does not work on some ***Dual Sim Huawei/Honor phones***.
- Use [LG drivers](http://www.mylgphones.com/lg-android-usb-device-drivers), in order for Android Studio to recognize LG phones.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve CellInfo().

Some devices Doesn't support **getAllCellInfo()**.

1. Try **telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()** (This method is deprecated but still supported by some devices)
2. To get cellinfo from that device try by building your App on SDK(API) 21.(**Not recommended**).

( App which are able to show all information are high likely builded and targeted on API 21 or less).

Answer (score 0):

It can be too late, but when you targeting to Android 10 or higher, you should call requestCellInfoUpdate

```
val subscriptionManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE)
                    as SubscriptionManager
            for (subs in subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
                val telephonyManager =
                    (getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager)
                        .createForSubscriptionId(subs.subscriptionId)
                telephonyManager.requestCellInfoUpdate(mainExecutor,
                    object : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
                        override fun onCellInfo(cellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
                            println("updated_cells_count: ${cellInfo.size}")
                        }

                        override fun onError(errorCode: Int, detail: Throwable?) {
                            super.onError(errorCode, detail)
                            println("updated_cells_error:\n")
                            detail?.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    })
            }
```